# How do I get the selected value in the dropdown and then display further information

Tags: database, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I have this dropdown that fetches the options from the database. I would like to know how can I get the value of that selected option then after selecting, other datas from the database will be displayed in a table or form?
It would look like this

Before selecting

Select from dropdown : option1

Name:
Age:

After Selecting

Select from dropdown : option2

Name: Michael
Age: 21

**Controller**

```
 public function salesorders() {
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            $this->header2();
            $data['groups'] = $this->secretary_model->getAllGroups();
            $this->load->view('secretary/transactions',$data);
        } else {
            redirect('secretary/sec_login_view');
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
function getAllGroups()
    {

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT firstname FROM tblcustomer');

        return $query->result();

    }
```

**View**

```
<?php 
            echo "Select Customer";
            $options = array();
            foreach($groups as $group)
            { 
              $options[$group->firstname] = $group->firstname;
            }
            echo form_dropdown('dropdown', $options);
            ?>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
                    <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered" >  
                        <thead >  
                            <tr>  
                                 <th>Order #</th> 
                                 <th>Customer Name </th>  
                                <th>Items</th>  
                                <th>Note</th>  
                                <th>Qtt.</th> 
                                <th>Total Price</th> 
                                <th>Shipping Address</th> 
                                <th>Status</th>  
                                <th>Edit</th>  

                            </tr>  
                        </thead>  
                        <tbody>
```

Comment: I would use jQuery and AJAX for that kind of task.

Comment: can you teach me how i would be doing it ? I really have no idea thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need to populate first dropdown fields on page loading, than you need AJAX call to another method where you would pass selected name. In that method you would have code that pass AJAX input value to model that returns data by value (in this case by name) wich you would echo as json_encode back to ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdownElementClass').on('change', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('secretary/getDataByName');?>", 
            data: { name: value }
        })
        .done(function( output ) {
              $('.classOfElementExpectingData').text( output );
        });
    });
});
```

//next code for controller

```
public function getDataByName()
{
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        echo $this->Secretary_model->getDataByName( $this->input->post('name') ) != FALSE ? json_encode( $this->Name_m->getDataByName( $this->input->post('name') ) ) : 'No data for selected name.' ;
    } else {
        echo 'No direct script access allowed.';
    }
}
```

There is fair amount of tutorials you can search on google or even on youtube for that. Study [this one](http://amitavroy.com/justread/content/articles/code-igniter-jquery-and-ajax), could help you though. Or you would search for something like "codeigniter ajax" on this place first. I believe you can find many similar questions and answers. Good luck.

Comment: thank you for this one I already have the dropdown populated although i still cant figure out the way to post the other datas

Comment: I am not sure what is your next issue. Example I coded for you and also link I found and posted do the job. If you don't see next step in your code, try this way.